# Mysql, executeall command for data in dictionary. Python

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I have this code :

```
sql = r"INSERT INTO table(par1,par2) VALUES ('%s',%d) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE par2=par2+VALUES(par2)"
```

(primary key is par1)
and a python dictionary that looks this way

```
dict = {'http://smth.com': 3,
        'http://smth2.com': 4}
```

The first value is a string and the other is a number. 
When I try to do cursor.executemany(sql, dict) it raises this error:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The default iterator over a dict only yields the dictionary keys, e.g.:

```
for k in dict(a=1, b=2, c=3):
    print k
```

will only print "a", "b", and "c", whereas you need key and value for the sql replacement.

Use the `iteritems` instead, these yield "complete" (key, value) pairs:

```
cursor.executemany(sql, dict.iteritems())
```

See:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems

As an aside, according to:
http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples
your format-specifiers should probably both be plain `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

This is python not being able to replace values of your dictionary into `sql`.

Not sure if a dictionary works, but [according to the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html), a list of tuples does the job:

```
data = [
  ('http://smth.com', 3),
  ('http://smth2.com', 4),
]
```